# Render Emojis in React UTF-8

Tags: reactjs, utf-8, word-cloud

I am trying to display the emojis received from my API into the WordCloud in React.
The characters received are in Unicode which are being converted into utf-8 format but not displaying the related emoji, rather just characters are displayed.

[image]

Here is my codesandbox for it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w286zyknrl?fontsize=14

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The response from your REST API looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"\u00f0\u0178\u02dc\u201a",
      "weight":1814
   },
   {
      "name":"\u00f0\u0178\u2122\u008f",
      "weight":1615
   },
   ...
```

It does not contain any emojis. If the first string `\u00f0\u0178\u02dc\u201a` is decoded, the result is ðŸ˜, exactly what's displayed.

Fix the REST service. It stores the emojis in an invalid format or using an invalid encoding/escaping for JSON.

Comment: But the REST service is storing the live tweet emojis in utf-8 format

Comment: It might be stored correclty. But the generated JSON is invalid. The problem is on the server side.

Comment: Is there any way to correct it on the server side? Since the REST API is not in my hand, I might need to tell it further so that it can be get changed

Comment: I hope it can be fixed on the server side. At the moment, it produces non-sense. `\u00f0\u0178\u02dc\u201a` is simply not a reasonable text and does not contain emojis.